# Spacing in french documents?

Tags: spacing, french

I am currently writing a letter in French. I know that in the French language there are some (for other european languages) unusual spacings near question marks, colons and french guillemets. I write in utf8, so I can use guillements directly. My question is if in my minimal example below all spacings are correct:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\signature{Bob le bricoleur}

\address{Je\\ne\\sais\\pas}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Ton\\adresse\\je\\crois}

\opening{Bonjour Bobette,}

j'espère que tu rapelle notre « arrangement ». La morale: il ne faut jamais pleurer. Tu sais ça?

\closing{Amicalement,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure if it would be better to make the needed spaces myself. Any ideas?

Comment: i'm certainly no expert on this, but if you don't want the guillemets to be able to separate from the text at a line break, you should put in an unbreakable space; the tilde `~` will "tie" them to the associated text, but otherwise act as an ordinary word space.  there should also be an unbreakable space before a question mark (or an exclamation mark, or a colon or semicolon). spacing after punctuation should be no different from ordinary word spacing -- use `\frenchspacing` to accomplish this. corrections from french-writing natives accepted.

Comment: For quotes, I advise the [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package. It should do anything automatically and is very powerful.

Comment: I would direct you to Daniel Flippo's [website](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/). He maintains the updated version of the french language files for `babel`, and from what I understand, his file should work, whether or not you use a tie (`~`).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the `utf8` options only translates the guillemets to the commands `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`. You can get automatically the space (even if you forget to write it) with `newunicodechar`. If you only use French, then

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{«}{\og}
\newunicodechar{»}{\fg}
```

is sufficient. If you use other languages, I recommend

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{«}{\iflanguage{francais}{\og}{\guillemotleft}}
\newunicodechar{»}{\iflanguage{francais}{\fg}{\guillemotright}}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{«}{\iflanguage{francais}{\og}{\guillemotleft}}
\newunicodechar{»}{\iflanguage{francais}{\fg}{\guillemotright}}

\signature{Bob le bricoleur}

\address{Je\\ne\\sais\\pas}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Ton\\adresse\\je\\crois}

\opening{Bonjour Bobette,}

j'espère que tu rapelle notre « arrangement ». La morale: il ne faut jamais pleurer. Tu sais ça?

j'espère que tu rapelle notre «arrangement». La morale: il ne faut jamais pleurer. Tu sais ça?

\closing{Amicalement,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

You'll see that the spacing is the same.

Comment: You write, "You'll see that the spacing is the same."  However, I get that the first ``« arrangement »``  has two spaces on the left-hand side and one space on the right-hand side, while the second one ``«arrangement»`` has one space on each side. Do you reproduce that? (Thanks)

Comment: @PatrickT I guess that things have changed in these three and a half years.

Comment: With an update TeX distribution in 2016, do `\frenchbsetup{og=«,fb=»}` instead of the `\newunicodechar` tricks.

Comment: That didn't work for me, as I'm on TeXlive 2015. But your other trick, ``\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{AB}{\og\ignorespaces}`` and 
``\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{BB}{\unskip\fg}`` is working for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's better use `french` option for `babel` and `\og` and `\fg` for guillemets:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\signature{Bob le bricoleur}

\address{Je\\ne\\sais\\pas}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Ton\\adresse\\je\\crois}

\opening{Bonjour Bobette,}

j'espère que tu rappelles notre \og arrangement\fg. La morale: il ne faut jamais pleurer. Tu sais ça?

\closing{Amicalement,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `francais` is a synonym for the `french` option in babel, so there should be no difference between the two.

Comment: I recommend reading http://perso.enstimac.fr/Gaborit~/latex/latex-in-french.html

Comment: @rpapa: the correct link is http://perso.enstimac.fr/~Gaborit/latex/latex-in-french.html and unfortunately some of the informations in it are outdated (e.g. package aeguill is obsolete, one should use fontenc with T1).

Comment: I just read about the babel option frenchb which I am currently using. `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` with
`\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=», GlobalLayoutFrench=true}`. Is there any difference between french and frenchb?

Comment: @Wauzl: on a recent distribution, the `french`, `frenchb` and `francais` options will all be equivalent (they were not at some point in the past, where the `french` option could call something else).

Answer (score -1):

You might use the package `microtype` and set the kerning to english or set the kerning after special characters manually. Have a look at p. 18f., 133, 136 and 187-9 of microtype.pdf. (There is even a command `\nonfrenchspacing`, which I've never used.)